# Identity Server 3 login via Javascript without redirect

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

Thinktecture Identity server has a good sample of logging in via the JavaScript client at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient

However, this particular example redirects the browser to the actual Identity Server URL (https://identityserverurl/login?signin=guidhere).

Is there a way to login via JavaScript without redirecting the browser and instead using JavaScript/Ajax calls? The primary intent is to better control the login flow for a single page application, which in some cases is also embedded in the HTML of another URL.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as OpenId Connect and Oauth protocols dont support such a flow.

Comment: So for example a login that uses a modal dialog (inline and not iframed) to login via JavaScript would not be feasible?

Comment: AFAIK this is not feasible.

Answer (score 3):

try resource owner credential flow that way u can use ur custome login flow..In that flow all u need is to hit the endpoints with username, password and in return u will get the token data(u can also include refresh token). Resource owner credential flow should only be used for trusted client applications. e.g., dropdox wind 8 app

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but resource owner credential flow surfaces the client secret, therefore (as you've stated) should only be used for trusted clients.  Therefore, it doesn't seem appropriate for JS clients, except in the situation where they're used in the same environment/context as the identity server instance, for example an intranet application.

Comment: Yes, you are right but there is a workaround(hack) to that. Call an API from the JS Client that will call Identity server with the client secret for you. This way it will become a server to server communication and your secret is not exposed. However recommended flow for JS Client if I am not wrong is implicit flow where you don't get any refresh token I think. You can also try Hybrid flow which I am currently using with my asp.net mvc application but then again it is server to server communication

Comment: @AtulChaudhary This is not the right way, we should not use this approach for SPA. You must use implicit flow and redirection is a must. Other are not secure